# Run-time Stack of C code

Tags: stack, callstack, lc3

I don't know if the title of my question is right, but I'm studying run-time stacks and I have the following C code:

```
int main() {
  int a, b, c , x;
  a = 4;
  b = 5
  c = 6
  x = func(a, b, c);
  return;
}
int func(int x, int y, int z) {
  int p, q, r;
  p = x*x;
  q = y/z;
  r = p + q;
  return r;
}
```

This is compiled and  loaded in location x3000.

I'm dealing with simulated computer called lc3. I need to find out how the run-time stack would look when this code is executed. My understanding of the topic is too limited in order to actually solve this, but here is how I think it should look:

```
x0000
      (I don't know how the return should look either)
      (Assignments that I don't know how to interpret)
      r
      q
      p
      main's frame pointer
      Return address to main
      Return value to main
      x a
      y b
      z c
      (I don't know the assignments should look in the run-time stack)
      x
      c
      b
      a
xEFFF
```

I hope someone can offer me some clarity in this subject. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this all depends on the ABI you are using. If it is anything similar to **SystemV x86 Abi** (the one in 32-bit linuxes). It should look like what you have described.  (I have modified my answer to match what the [wikipedia describes for LC-3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LC-3))

first of all, you reach `main()`, and have 4 local variables, each of one is an `int`. (Assuming each `int` is 4 bytes, and stack aligned to 4 bytes), they will be stored in:

```
0xEFFC: a
0xEFF8: b
0xEFF4: c
0xEFF0: x
```

Then you call a function, namely `func()`. The LC-3 abi says that the parameters must be passed on the stack, from rigth to left:

```
0xEFEC: z --> c
0xEFE8: y --> b
0xEFE4: x --> a
```

Then you should save space for the return value, put the return address, and save your R5:

```
0xEFE0: Return value
0xEFDC: Return address to main
0xEFD8: Space for R5
```

Local variables again:

```
0xEFD4: p
0xEFD0: q
0xEFCC: r
```

On modern systems, the return value can be passed in registers (like EAX). It depends on your ABI where to pass it. Probably it can be returned on the stack too.

Another thing is that each function can create an stack frame, pushing into the stack the parent's Base Stack Address, and assuming their stack starts from that address.

You should probably have a document in where all these things are defined.